# Switch CSS to SCSS Jhipster style

Tags: css, sass, jhipster

I decide to use scss instead of css in my project, but I'm having real hard time with switch manually the project, i want to know if there's a way to switch to scss in a clean way by jhipster or maybe i have to regenerate the app from the start and select scss in the configuration? this way should work fine but it will take really long time to get the app back in the actual state. I'm looking for a better solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a git branch, edit .yo-rc.json, enable sass, re-generate your app using `jhipster --with-entities` then merge into your master branch using the git merge strategy that suits you to keep your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-to-scss). You can use it as an executable or as a library. The installation and usage are described in detail in the page linked above.